# C# MVC Multilingual not working with RESX files

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, multilingual, adminlte

I am using AdminLTE MVC with Visual Studio. I would like to implement multilingual system and one way to do this seems to use RESX files.

The default langage of my website will be French (fr).
So, I created 2 files and saves them in my "/Resources/" folder :

[image]

I specified the "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" property on each RESX files.

Then, in my **RouteConfig.cs** file, I added a new **routes.MapRoutes** to enerate url with langage like www.mywebsite.com/fr/MyController :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       /* routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );*/

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "ML",
          url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { lang = "fr", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

For a simple test, I only added 1 variable in my RESX files. For the French version :
[image]

And the English version :
[image]

Then, in my view Index.cshtml I simply display the content of "Valeur" value :

```
@using Resources;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    ViewBag.Description = "Home Page";
}


<div>
    The current Value is : <b>@Resources.CDV.Valeur</b>
</div>
```

Finaly when I load my page, I only get the French version :
[image]

When I call the /en/ page the CDV.en.resx is not loaded : 
[image]

Do you have any idea of what I did wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to annoy people with 2 reCaptcha's?

Comment: Have you tried to choose`English` in your regional settings?

Comment: What do you mean "regional settings" : on the browser ?

Comment: Why have you edited an old question for a current issue, instead of posting a new question?

Comment: Because I can not add one question with my account... it's blocked